# trying to loop at the import function

Tags: excel, vba

1. When i import files, the previous database will be shifted to the right instead of it being deleted. How do i loop/do it in such a way that whenever i import a file, the previous database will be deleted?

I tried to use "For Each filename As ActiveWorkSheet" but it doesn't work

```
Sub ImportFiles()

    'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    
    

    'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Declare a variable to contain the path
    'of each selected item. Even though the path is aString,
    'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
    'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
    With fd
    
        'Set the initial path to the C:\ drive.
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
        'Add a filter that includes  the list.
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "CMOS-log", "*.log", 1

        'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
        'The user pressed the button.
        If .Show = -1 Then

            'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

                'vrtSelectedItem is aString that contains the path of each selected item.
                'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
                'This example displays the path in a message box.
                Path = Left(vrtSelectedItem, InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
                filename = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
                Call ImportCMOSLog(Path, filename)
                Call InsertTimeCol
                Call FormatHeadline
                
        'The user pressed Cancel.
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With

    'Set the object variable to Nothing.
    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub


Sub ImportCMOSLog(Path As String, filename As String)
    Sheets("Data").Select
    'Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = filename
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = filename
    Range("A2").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Path & filename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))              'I've changed A2 to A1 instead
        .Name = filename
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = False
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

2. While running my code, sometimes my sheet name will change despite me declaring to paste the database there with that specific name. Am i doing it wrong or is there some way to lock it?

Comment: Do you really want changing the name of `Sheets("Data")` with `filename`? If yes, you do not have a sheet named "Data" at the next iteration... Which sheet do you think should be `ActiveSheet` when you try `ActiveSheet.Name`? And why `On Error Resume Next` in that `Sub`?

Comment: i dont want to change the file name. i just want the file to be placed on a sheet called "Data". On error resume next is for me to debug

Comment: But `On error Resume Next` das not let you really debugging... Anyhow, try the next changes: Comment the line `Sheets("Data").Select`. Then change ` With ActiveSheet.QueryTables...` with `Sheets("Data").QueryTables...` and qualify `Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1"))`. And comment the line `On Error Resume Next`. It only does not allow to VBA to raise an error and see where your problem is. Of course, in case of an error, but you must know it!

Comment: Ooo, that makes more sense! Do you perhaps know why do i face a repeated loop in my database once i import another file?

Comment: Since, your code always creates the query in A1, it overwrite the existing one. What do you want accomplishing, in fact? I cannot deduce only looking at your code...

Comment: In fact it didnt overwrite it. I have 55 columns. When i don't manually delete the data that was originally in the sheet named "Data", it actually stores at column 56 onwards

Comment: I cannot understand how it is possible, since the destination is the same... Please, define what "a repeated loop in my database" should mean.

Comment: If it translates the query range and you need it to be deleted, why don't you delete it in code? I also thought it should be overwritten...  Do you want deleting only the last one, or all existing? For the last one, you should use `sh.QueryTables(sh.QueryTables.count).Delete`, where `sh` is your `Sheets("Data")` sheet...

Comment: i want to delete all the existing ones. Thank you so much!

Comment: Then, you need to iterate between them. Something like: `For i = 1 To sh.QueryTables.count`  `sh.QueryTables(i).Delete`  `Next i`. On three code lines. And, of course, `sh` is the same `Sheets("Data")` sheet...

Comment: Understood! Thank you for assisting me! Very much appreciated!